# Throttle Reactjs Event System

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I have a [splitpane](https://github.com/tomkp/react-split-pane) component with my React project, upon re-size panes will react to their width and change content. The Split pane component has the following event listners...

```
    componentDidMount: function() {
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp);
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove);
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
    }
    onMouseUp: function() {
    //firing here
    },
```

I have viewed the dev tools timeline and the events are firing too often, and the page is not performing to expectations. How can I throttle these events?

Edit - thanks for the quick reply, I would like to use a timer and not introduce another module, I know for a fact its not the state change since it only changes at 3 breakpoints, and the timeline shows events firing too often (yellow)

My check for state -

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
        console.log("STATED CHANGED")
        console.log(nextState.showStackingTableState)
        console.log(this.state.showStackingTableState)
        return nextState.showStackingTableState !== this.state.showStackingTableState;
},
```

Update - I am thinking I should do it this way...if mouse down, then trigger a boolean, if the boolean is true then throttle, else false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it the events that are firing too often, or how you're handling the events (e.g. causing too many re-renders)? I'm betting it's the latter, and if so, you can simply throttle it with a timer, or use a helper like [Underscore's `throttle`](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle).

Comment: @Rkhayat What work is being done in `onMouseMove`? I would not expect the events simply firing to cause an issue; after all, the browser emits these same events. I would expect the `onMouseMove` *handler*, or some other function downstream, to be doing work too often (e.g. in the project, it gets the computed styles of elements, which causes browser reflow and could be slow). *That's* what I wold throttle.

Comment: It's the mouseMove that is slow, which calculates the sizes of the pane, the graph is all yellow during that time, and mouseMove is the bottleneck.

Comment: @Rkhayat I would give throttling the `onMouseMove` event handler a shot. There are [simple implementations](https://github.com/brianloveswords/throttle-function) that don't require underscore as well.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Shouldn't the following work? `  document.addEventListener('mousemove', $.throttle(1000, this.onMouseMove));`

Comment: @Rkhayat (After your edit) Yes. I would probably do something like `this.onMouseMove = $.throttle(1000, this.onMouseMove)` in a `componenntWillMount` hook